# How to reshape tensor without graph disconnect in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Reshaping tensor with `tf.reshape` during forward pass causes disconnect error in TensorFlow.

For example,

```
    ...
    image = tf.keras.layers.Input(INPUT_SHAPE, name='image', dtype=tf.uint8)  
    image = tf.reshape(image, shape = (-1, 1344, 768, 1))
    image_norm = normalize(image)
    ...
```

Above code causes the following error

> Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
> KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8, 1344, 768, 1),
> dtype=tf.uint8, name='image'), name='image', description="created by
> layer 'image'") at layer "tf.reshape". The following previous layers
> were accessed without issue: []

Is there any way to reshape tensor without disconnet?

Comment: How do you define the model? Is it by chance something like `tf.keras.Model(image, ...)`? In that case, you may want to keep the `image` variable pointing to `tf.keras.layers.Input(INPUT_SHAPE, name='image', dtype=tf.uint8)` and use another variable for `tf.reshape(image, shape = (-1, 1344, 768, 1))`.

Comment: Your guess is exactly right! Thank you! I made a very basic mistake.